# How we can use the newly launched machine IP in a configuration file

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible to create droplet in Digital Ocean and configure it at boot time. All things are working fine.

Now i need to use the Newly created server IP in my one configuration file, so i want to make this change also at boot time configuration to avoid manually changes.

I am thinking it is possible via taking the IP of server in Variable and later i can use this variable in lineinfile module to replace a line in my configuration file.

Can anybody please help me how we can store the server IP in a variable?

Below is my `ansible-playbook`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create new DO Droplet
    digital_ocean:
     state: present
     command: droplet
     name: ansibletest
     api_token: xyz
     size_id: '1gb'
     region_id: ams3
     image_id: '41695378'
     ssh_key_ids: '23625200'
    register: my_droplet
  - name: print info about my_droplet
    local_action:
      module:  debug
         msg= "ID is {{ my_droplet.droplet.id }} IP is {{  my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
  - name: Add new droplet to host group
    local_action: add_host hostname={{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} groupname=launched
  - name: Wait for SSH to come up
    local_action: wait_for host={{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
- hosts: launched
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: installing python for dependencies
    raw: |
     set -e
     if [ -x /usr/bin/python ]; then exit 0; fi
     export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
     apt-get update
     apt-get install -y python
  - name: update repo
    apt:
     update_cache: yes
  - name: install the list of below packages
    apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=true
    with_items:  
        - build-essential
        - tcl
        - libjemalloc-dev
  - name: downoad and unarchive the redis file
    unarchive: src=http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz dest=/home copy=no
  - name: run make command to install redis
    command: "{{ item }} chdir=/home/redis-stable"
    with_items:
        - make
        - make test
        - make install
  - name: ufw enable
    ufw: 
    state: enabled
     policy: allow
  - name: open ufw and allow port
    ufw:
     rule: allow
     proto: tcp
     port: 22
  - name: copy redis.conf file
    copy:
     src: /etc/ansible/redis.conf 
     dest: /home/redis-stable/redis.conf
  - name: copy sentinel.conf
    copy:
     src: /etc/ansible/sentinel.conf
     dest: /home/redis-stable/sentinel.conf
  - name: making change in the sentinel.conf file
    lineinfile:
     path: /etc/ansible/sentinel.conf
     regexp: '^sentinel monitor'
     line: 'sentinel monitor mymaster {{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} 6379 2'
```

Below is the my error:

`"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'my_droplet' is undefined`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that it is this statement:

```
line: 'sentinel monitor mymaster {{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} 6379 2'
```

in the second play that is causing the issue, registered variables do not directly persist between plays. Additionally, even if they did, your first play is on a different host to those addressed in the second play. Instances of registered variables are only directly available to the host that they were registered on.

It is possible however, to access registered variables through the hostvars system. This allows one host to access the variables associated with another and is commonly used to access facts gathered in the fact system. Registered variables are also available through this method. Basic form is:

```
line: 'sentinel monitor mymaster {{ hostvars['some_host_in_your_inventory'].variable_name }} 6379 2'
```

or

```
line: 'sentinel monitor mymaster {{ hostvars['some_host_in_your_inventory']['variable_name'] }} 6379 2'
```

In your particular case, you want to access the 'my_droplet' variable that was *registered on the control machine* ('localhost'). This likely won't be in your inventory file, but you always get localhost for free automatically. Therefore try this in your code:

```
line: 'sentinel monitor mymaster {{ hostvars['localhost'].my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} 6379 2'
```

Comment: thank you for your response and for guiding me in right direction.
This issue is fixed. But now i have one more question which you already replied in your answer. But i have few doubts in that i.e I am launching droplet and configuring it using ansible at boot time. Now I need to use the IP of one server in another server configuration file. The hosts inventory `launched` used by me does not exists on my ansible node. Then how we can do that. I am confused.
Please help me.

Comment: I am not entirely clear what you are requesting. To access facts from another host, you use hostvars['name']. Name has to be inside single quotes and the name that is used to refer to the host in the inventory. So if this is an IP you can do hostvars['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']. One caveat is that to access fact from another host, they need to first have been collected. I will update my answer with some additional detail.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you see my ansible playbook posted in first post it launch droplet and configure that at first time boot. Let say i have created one master machine and now need to create two slave machine and need to use the master machine IP in slave machine configuration. 

Now the issue i am facing is that i did't make entry of master host in any inventory because its in localhost.

So how i can get the master machine IP and use same in my slave configuration.

Comment: I have re-written my answer as it looks like I was confusing matters, rather than making them better :) Hopefully that gets you up and running.

Comment: After reading your post i got that we can call the register variable in the second play using `hostvar` but it will make changes over same machine.

But my question is that I need to use the IP of already created machine in another machine which will also create using same playbook. As per my knowledge when i will run this playbook the value of localhost will be overwrite with new values. Then how I can call the IP of already created machine in newly creating machine.

The question might still might not be clear due to my bad English.

Comment: What I wrote in my rewritten answer will work for the playbook in your question. It sounds like you are now asking about a difference case. If so, please update your question with a short example playbook of what you are trying to do.